# PHP load all lines between 2 lines matching strpos and move to array

Tags: php, string, strpos

I have a text file with a bunch of information in it.  I need to pull all lines that are between 2 lines, where these two lines match a string.

Here is an example of what the file would look like:

```
def var test:1
def string myString:My String

do start_sequence
do perform:1
wait
do perform:2
do end_sequence

def var testTwo:2
do perform:3
```

This file gets output by another system which I cannot modify.  What I need to do is load all lines between `do start_sequence` and `do end_sequence`.  I will then be loading these lines into an array(this part I can handle without a problem).

Right now I am turning the entire file into an array, each new line is a new value in the array.  How can I pull out all values between the matching strings(`do start_sequence` and `do end_sequence`) and put them in a separate array?

Comment: So in other words, when you find a certain string you want to get all data until you encounter that string again?

Comment: A multi-line regex using `preg_match()` would do this.

Answer (score 1):

Took a shot and here's what I came up with.

It uses `$reading` to denote whether or not it should be writing the lines to another variable. Hope this helps.

```
$data = <<< EOF
def var test:1
def string myString:My String

do start_sequence
do perform:1
wait
do perform:2
do end_sequence

def var testTwo:2
do perform:3
EOF;

$lines = explode("\n", $data);

$data = array();

$reading = false;
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    if ($reading == true && $line == 'do end_sequence')
        $reading = false;

    if ($reading)
    {
        $data[] = $line;
    }

    if ($line == 'do start_sequence')
        $reading = true;
}

var_dump($data);
```

This will output the following

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'do perform:1' (length=12)
  1 => string 'wait' (length=4)
  2 => string 'do perform:2' (length=12)
```

Answer (score 1):

I went with a regex solution just for fun - http://regexr.com/39i6o

```
(do perform)(?:.|[\n\r])+(?=do end_sequence)
```

Here is the PHP code that will put each line into an array -

```
$pattern = '/(do perform)(?:.|[\n\r])+(?=do end_sequence)/';
preg_match($pattern, $data, $matches);  
$newArray = explode("\n",trim($matches[0]));
```

[Working example.](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/tkfz-g32p)

Comment: What about a subtle addition to consider UNIX line breaks? *(?:.|[\n\r]|[\n])*

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions like this:

```
$text = file_get_contents('t.txt');
preg_match_all("/.*do start_sequence(.*)do end_sequence.*/s", $text, $matches);
```

Inside `$matches[1]` you will have the portion of the text you want in raw format (just as it is in the file). Then you can split the lines as you are already doing with the full file.

Comment: Testing your regex and it doesn't return anything. Are you assuming a string?

Comment: Well, not really: I took OP's sample file and put into that _t.txt_, then used the code above. I get the whole file in `$matches[0]` and the searched portion in `$matches[1]`.  In any case, I liked your expression better, more elegant.

Comment: Ah - cool. I just ran yours through Regexpal just for a look and couldn't get a match.

Comment: The **s** flag is the one that deals with line breaks, without that it won't work... maybe that's why?

Comment: No, I used the modifier. I'm not sure what the issue was but even when I erased all of your regex to start with `.*do start_sequence(.*)d` it fails to make any match even as I continue your pattern to the end.

Comment: I don't know really; I used phpliveregex.com to build it, it works there.

Answer (score 0):

since you have an array of strings , just knowing the index of startString and the endString solves your problem.

```
$a=array ("A","B","C","Comes before","D","E");
$startIndex=array_search("A", $a);
$endIndex= array_search("D", $a);
$neddedArray=  array_slice($a, $startIndex+1,($endIndex-$startIndex)-1);
print_r($neddedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$originalString = file_get_contents('yourFile.txt');
$tempArray = explode('do start_sequence', $originalString);
$str = explode('do end_sequence', $tempArray[1]);
$finalArray = $explode('\n', $str[0]);
```